# Lambda.FunctionError In my elasticsearch service log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda function that connects to Kinesis Firehose delivery streams. In my logs the lambda function is executing perfectly and returning the data I want.

On my Kinesis Firehose delivery streams dashboard  in the monitoring section it looks like I am getting Incoming bytes and Incoming records since there is data in those graphs. there is also data in the ExecuteProcessing Duration graph but then the ExecuteProcessing Success graph shows a line at 0, so I am guessing it is failing.

In the Elasticsearch logs I am getting a

> Lambda.FunctionError with a message that says:  The Lambda function
>   was successfully invoked but it returned an error result.

I am new to working with AWS and I am having trouble debugging this error code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you must check is the return output of function. Remember that you must return a array with the same number of records in the following structure:

```
output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    }
output.append(output_record)
**return {'records': output}**
```

if you forget  return this array , you will get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

If the Lambda function is returning an error, then you should be able to find more information in the CloudWatch logs for the function in question. [These docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html) describe the different ways to access the logs. If the logs don't provide enough information, you might considering altering the function to write more information to stdout or stderr.